# Toyota aygo has knocking noises from front and back?

Tags: ball-joint

I think I know why the knocking is coming from the front as it just passed it’s MOT with an advisory of the front arm ball joint has slight play. But I have no clue why the back is making a noise, I notice even if I move around in the car it makes the clunking noises and I’m not a heavy person so couldn’t just be that.

Comment: Nice question. Is there any more information or diagnostic attempts you could add to make it easier to recommend solutions? I'm not an expert, but I might use a different term to describe the sound, "knocking" is often associated with engine knocking.

Comment: Best to include  year & mileage

Answer (score 1):

A few common places to look at to start with would be, Exhaust brackets and hangers, heat shields and protective shields, suspension and or wishbones can cause banging and knocking noises.

Comment: Your brief comment could easily be a valid answer if you expand it slightly.

Comment: Are all of those costly repairs?

Comment: Dont believe likely for exhaust components to make noise from getting in the car

Answer (score 0):

If car has over 70k miles I would say very likely sway bar bushings [cheap] can chk it by pounding the sway bar with youre hand near the mounts (Google location if necessary) or bad strut mount which is @ the top of the struts it sometimes cracks and can rattle like crazy not as easy to chk need to remove rear tray sometimes also rear seats. (more expensive due to labor). unfortunately I would say most likely cause is that actual  strut is bad meaning it lost resistance a replacement will run you about $300 by a mechanic. However you can purchase an after market & install ureself for between $80 & $120 it's  not that hard if youre handy, just make sure to get a loaded strut & watch a youtube video. another thing gotta watch outfor the swaybar link bolts